# Rails loads some assets, but not all

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've had several images in my `app/assets/images` folder for quite some time (2+ years), but today I just realized that some of the images are not loading and I can't figure out why. Just simply renaming the "broken" files does the trick (it loads with the new filename) and it makes no sense to me.

I have an HTML page that loads these images through just `https://mysite/assets/file_name.png`. As you can see in the screenshot below, the top two images are working, but the bottom two aren't.

[image]

The images are in the following paths:

- app/assets/images/severity_icons/medium-impact.png
- app/assets/images/severity_icons/medium-top-vulns.png
- app/assets/images/severity_icons/medium-recommendation.png
- app/assets/images/severity_icons/medium-reproduction.png

Here's the files on the actual server itself:

```
root@670e1c54cdd6:/myapp/app/assets/images/severity_icons$ ls -l medium*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8831 Nov  6 03:03 medium-impact.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 9321 Nov  6 03:03 medium-recommendation.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 9468 Nov  6 03:03 medium-reproduction.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 9762 Nov  6 03:03 medium-top-vulns.png
```

So in the above example, the `medium-recommendation.png` file doesn't load:

```
I, [2022-11-06T16:27:17.195355 #191]  INFO -- : [8a73e9a4-fbc7-4c30-87a0-f7f35959afcd] Started GET "/assets/medium-recommendation.png" for [obfuscated IP] at 2022-11-06 16:27:17 +0000                                                                                                                                                              
F, [2022-11-06T16:27:17.206898 #191] FATAL -- : [8a73e9a4-fbc7-4c30-87a0-f7f35959afcd]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
[8a73e9a4-fbc7-4c30-87a0-f7f35959afcd] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/medium-recommendation.png"):
```

even though it's in the same folder and precompiled with `rake assets:precompile` at the same time as the other files. Again, if I rename `medium-recommendation` to `medium-r`, it works:

```
➜  ~ curl https://mysite/assets/medium-recommendation.png
<html><body>You are being <a href="https://mysite/">redirected</a>.</body></html>%
➜  ~ curl https://mysite/assets/medium-r.png
Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell
Warning: curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output
Warning: <FILE>" to save to a file.
```

Comment: You shouldn't be be calling assets directly. If you compile them, there should be a long string added to the file name. The way to access the compile assets is `image_tag "severity_icons/medium-impact.png"` and rails will infer the fingerprinted path. Also you can use `asset_path "severity_icons/medium-impact.png"` if you just want the path.

Comment: Calling `image_tag("severity_icons/medium.png")` just simply returns "/severity_icons/medium.png". Am I missing something in my assets configuration?

Comment: In development, in production it will pick the fingerprinted path. That's why I asked what it the path to both the working images and the broken images. None of them should be just the filename of the image, but a fingerprinted filename.

Comment: Understood. It turns out that dropping the extension ".png" seemed to do the trick. Have no idea why this worked.